# Quill Editor won't display v-model in input field (Vue 3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, wysiwyg, quill, vue-quill-editor

I want to display some `html`, fetched from a database inside of `quill editor`. The `html` seems to be fine (displayed in `<p>` paragraph) and is bound to `quill editor` via `v-model` but it just does not get displayed:

```html
<template>
  <div id="text-editor" class="text-editor">
    <quill-editor :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="store.re.body" contentType="html"/>
    <p>{{store.re.body}}</p>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'
import store from "../../../js/store";

store.re.body = ''

const modules = {
    module: BlotFormatter,
}

const toolbar = [
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    ['link', 'image', 'video'],
    ['clean']
];
</script>
```

This is where the data gets fetched from the database (inside another vue component):

```js
axios.get('/get-blog', {
        params: {
            id: state.id
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        state.body = store.re.body = res.data[0].body
    })
    .catch(err => {
        state.error = true
        setTimeout(() => state.error = false, 5000)
    })
```

I am using `store.re.body` (reactive store) to transport it to `quill editor`.

**`store.js`**:

```js
import {reactive} from "vue";

const re = reactive({})

export default {
    re
}
```

Here you can see the `editor page` displayed, below with working `<p>` paragraph but the editor input stays empty:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `quill-editor` component does not watch `props.content` ([`vueup/vue-quill#35`](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/35)). The watch was [removed in an attempt to fix another bug, where the cursor would reset to the beginning of the line](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/commit/f2bf17150ddfe87e8ba6ff80e16fe2602f84fbd4).

As a workaround, add your own watch on `content`, and call `quill-editor`'s [`setHTML()`](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/api/methods.html#sethtml-html) with the new value. However, you'll need to move the cursor to the end of the line (using Quill's [`setSelection()`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setselection)) to workaround the bug mentioned above:

```html
<template>
  <quill-editor ref="quill" v-model:content="content" ⋯/>
</template>

<script setup>
import store from '@/store'
import { watch, ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

const content = ref('')
const quill = ref(null)
let newContent = ''

watch(content, newValue => {
  newContent = newValue
  store.re.body = newValue
})

watch(
  () => store.re.body,
  newValue => {
    if (newContent === newValue) return

    quill.value.setHTML(newValue)

    // Workaround https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/52
    // move cursor to end
    nextTick(() => {
      let q = quill.value.getQuill()
      q.setSelection(newValue.length, 0, 'api')
      q.focus()
    })
  }
)

⋮
</script>

<template>
  <quill-editor ref="quill" ⋯/>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-quill-update-content-etk8jd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyEditor.vue)

Answer (score 1):

for me, using

```
v-model:value="form.html" @input="val => form.html= val"
```

worked... I think they not yet comply to new Vue3 model standards

Answer (score 0):

**you should try with these example bellow**

```js
    <script>
     import {QuillEditor} from "@vueup/vue-quill";
     export default {
       components: {
         QuillEditor, 
       },
 data(){
    return {
     someText:''
   }
}, 
   computed: {
     editor() {
      return this.$refs.quillEditor;
     },
   },
   methods: {
     getSetText() {
       this.someText = "<div><p>this is some text</p> </div>";
       this.editor.setHTML(this.someText);
      },
     }, 
   }
 </script>
```

```html
    <template><quill-editor ref="quillEditor" contentType="html"v-model:content="someText" theme="snow" ></quill-editor></template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when getting content from a data, I solved adding this on mounted:

```
 document.querySelector(".ql-editor").innerHTML = item.value.content
```

I hope it helps. Thx